# inline css style width not able to override computed css style's width value

Tags: css, html

I'm seeing a strange behaviour which i'm not able to figure out.

The webpage that i'm working on has a lot of css styles. So for one of my div's i'm using inline css to make the width as per my requirement (which shows up in the source code just fine). But when i'm inspecting the element in Google Chrome i see that the computed width as slightly less than my value. How do i override the computed value.

Thanks

Comment: sounds like the classic `inline` element needs `display:block;` or `display:inline-block;` problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try with !important to override any value.

```
#div {width:500px !important;}
```

Comment: hi miduga, I added <div style="width: 200px !important;"> .. </div>. Still the computed width is shown as 193px. Anything else i should do?

Comment: Make sure that the div you're trying to align is of the display type block or inline-block. You can't define the width for inline elements.

Comment: Then Raja, may be the problem that says Exelian or maybe you've an !important statment in another place that is breaking it!

Answer (score 3):

Could you please provide more sample code. This is not enough information to answer the question properly. As stated by miduga, `!important` should be enough to override that style.

Are you certain that this element is of the correct display type? Remember that you can't define a width for inline elements.